# How to feed a variable to a command's parameter?

Tags: python, maya

I am super noob and I have been researching this all day to no avail.
This is my quest : I want to iterate through a list of objects and connect one of their attributes to another object's attribute. For the sake of the example, let's say I want to feed in nurbsCircle's translate X into every other object's translate Y.

My attempt looks like this :

```
    import maya.cmds as cmds

sel = cmds.ls(selection=True)

for obj in sel:
    cmds.connectAttr(nurbsCircle1 + '.tx', second + '.ty')
```

...but I don't know how to tell Maya the second term ("second") should be "every object in selection" instead of a fixed thing.

I got help from this :
[Maya python connect attributes of selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288662/maya-python-connect-attributes-of-selection)

I know this is probably dead simple. I hope someone can help me.

Hadriscus

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `obj` is.

```
for obj in sel:
    cmds.connectAttr(nurbsCircle1 + '.tx', obj + '.ty')
```